Github ActionsにてFlutterのCI/CDの動作確認をしていますが、ストアへのアップロードでエラーになります
先ほど別の質問をしていた続きです。
Github ActionsでFlutterのCI/CDでaabのビルドでエラーになります
ビルドが出来たのでストアにアップロードしたいのですがエラーになっています。
ビルドしたaabファイルが見つからないのでアップロード出来ないという状況です。
build.gradle、ワークフロー、エラーを以下に記載します。
対応方法やご意見いただけると助かります。
android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Workflow.yaml
name: Flutter CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-android:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Set up Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          flutter-version: '3.24.5'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: flutter pub get

      - name: Create local.properties
        run: |
          echo "flutter.sdk=$HOME/flutter" > $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/android/local.properties
          echo "sdk.dir=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT" >> $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/android/local.properties

      - name: Analyze code
        run: flutter analyze

      - name: Run tests
        run: flutter test

      - name: Create secrets directory
        run: mkdir -p $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/android/app/secrets

      # キーストアファイルをBase64からデコードしてファイルとして配置
      - name: Decode Keystore
        run: echo '${{ secrets.ENCODED_RELEASE_KEYSTORE }}' | base64 --decode > $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/android/app/secrets/playstore.keystore

      # aabファイルを生成
      - name: Generate AAB
        run: ./gradlew :app:bundleRelease --console=plain
        working-directory: android
        env:
          KEYSTORE_ALIAS: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_ALIAS }}
          KEYSTORE_ALIAS_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_ALIAS_PASSWORD }}
          KEYSTORE_STORE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_STORE_PASSWORD }}

      - name: List build outputs
        run: ls -R $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/build

      # シークレットに設定したサービスアカウントキーをファイルとして配置
      - name: Create service_account.json
        id: createServiceAccount
        run: echo '${{ secrets.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON }}' > service_account.json

      # Google Play Storeの内部テストトラックにアップロードする
      - name: Deploy to Play Store
        id: deploy
        uses: r0adkll/upload-google-play@v1.1.2
        with:
          serviceAccountJson: service_account.json
          packageName: jp.co.githubactionsMobileappsTest
          releaseFiles: $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab
          track: internal
          # 未公開のアプリはstatusをdraftに指定する必要あり
          status: draft

エラーです。
Deploy to Play Store

Run r0adkll/upload-google-play@v1.1.2
  with:
    serviceAccountJson: service_account.json
    packageName: jp.co.githubactionsMobileappsTest
    releaseFiles: $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab
    track: internal
    status: draft
    inAppUpdatePriority: 0
    changesNotSentForReview: false
  env:
    JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/17.0.13-11/x64
    FLUTTER_ROOT: /opt/hostedtoolcache/flutter/stable-3.24.5-x64
    PUB_CACHE: /home/runner/.pub-cache
Error: Unable to find any release file matching $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab

「List build outputs」では以下の出力があり、ファイルは存在すると思っていますが、何が悪いのかわからないです。
/home/runner/work/githubactions_mobileapps_test/githubactions_mobileapps_test/build/app/outputs/bundle/release:
app-release.aab

